# food waste disposer (a garbitrator)

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal

I want to install food waste disposer, my pipes are 1.5 inch and I've heard that the pipes should be 2 inch otherwise after a couple of years the pipes will start clogging. 
I'm trying to understand if it's true.
Thanks

Comment: A quick search found references to 1-1/2" pipe being typical. No reference to pipe size in the one manufacturer's disposal installation manual that I looked up.

Comment: 1 1/2" is the standard size for the waste pipes under a kitchen sink. There should be no problem as long as you use the disposer as directed (always run water, batch feed/no overloading, etc.)

Comment: Disposers are a maintenance headache, a water waster, and put food waste into the sanitary sewer. Food waste should go into the garbage. Many municipalities in the US recommend against kitchen disposers because sewage treatment is not necessary for food waste and it adds to the load of the sewage treatment plants.